S3 access denied when making the API call in IOS 18 beta version
When I am trying to send my image to aws using amplify plugin, I am having this problem on my iOS device 18 beta for else previous version its work fine:
 StorageAccessDeniedException {
 
User contributions licensed under CC BY-SA (content policy)

   "message": "S3 access denied when making the API call.",
   "recoverySuggestion": "HTTP error returned from service, review the `underlyingException` for details.",
   "underlyingException": "Instance of 'UnknownSmithyHttpException'"
 }

I am currently having the latest flutter version 3.24.2 and amplify_flutter: ^2.4.1, amplify_auth_cognito: ^2.4.1, amplify_storage_s3: Using ^2.4.1

What makes you think your code should be permitted to the S3 bucket? Does it have an IAM Policy or is there a Bucket Policy on the S3 bucket? If so, please Edit your Question to add more details.

upgradtion directly will not work, there are breaking changes you have to modify code,
https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/flutter/start/project-setup/upgrade-guide/

You want to interact with Amazon S3 from a IOS app. Why are you not using the AWS SDK for Swift for developing IOS apps?
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/swift

Future<double> amplifyUpload() async{
    double progressbar = 0.0;
    try {
      var respOrg = await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
       localFile: AWSFile.fromPath('/path/to/local/file.txt'),
       path: const StoragePath.fromString('public/example.txt'),
        onProgress: (progress) {
          progressbar = progress.fractionCompleted;
          safePrint('Fraction completed: ${progress.fractionCompleted}');
        },
      ).result;
      safePrint('Uploaded file: ${respOrg.uploadedItem.path}');
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Exception occurred: $e');
      progressbar = -1.0;
    }
    return progressbar;
  }


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
